# Object of class DateTime cannot be converted to string in my code

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

```
$timestamp = "$day/$month/$year 00:00:00";
$timestamp = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i:s', $timestamp);

echo $timestamp->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

What should I do with it?

Answer (score 2):

```
$timestamp = new DateTime();
echo $timestamp->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Is it that you're looking for?